# Execute command when replicating database on publisher and subscriber?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two MSSQL 2012 databases.
I have snapshot replication configured where the first server is a publisher and distributer, and the other is a subscriber.

I would like to be able to execute a command on the publisher just before the replication job occurs, and then another command on the subscriber just after the replication finishes.

I belive this should be a pull snapshot replication, so that the agent is located on the subscriber server.

Is this even possible?

EDIT. Due to the nature of snapshot replication, i switched to using transactional replication, thus removing my ability to execute scripts on replication-start and -stop.

Answer (score 0):

I never did find a way to execute commands successfully when data is replicating, as i switched to transactional replication. The job handling this transaction type, will start and then just keep running, and not like snapshot replication where the job starts - replicates data - stops.

Instead i set up the jobs i needed executed, using the task scheduler. My services transfers files, to and from a webserver, through the database. And will only transfer files if not already present.

Using task scheduler is working pretty good, and it is MUCH more simple and stable than having something execute a sql script, which would then execute a powershell remoting command to connecto to the server and execute the service.

I just thought i would add this if anyone else stumbles on a similar problem :)